# Please help me on understanding this XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I came across this XPath in one of my studying code:

```
  count($recprv//*[local-name()='provider_email' or local-name()='provider_fax' 
  or local-name()='provider_phone' or local-name()='provider_phone_ext' ])
```

I am now having a hard time figuring out what it means, I personally think it says:" in the xml file recprv, count the number of any elements that contain either provider_email or contains provider_fax or contains provider_phone or contains provider_phone_ext.

So it will basically go through the xml file recprc and count all of the records? Just a bit confused. Moreover, I would love to know what is EXACTLY being counted in the count function. Thanks a lot for helping me out here!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 count($recprv//*
            [local-name()='provider_email'
           or 
            local-name()='provider_fax'  
          or 
            local-name()='provider_phone' 
          or 
            local-name()='provider_phone_ext' 
            ]
       )
```

**This means**:

*Give me the count of all elements that are contained in any of the trees contained in the variable* `$recprv`, *whose* **[local-name()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-local-name)** (the part of the name following the namespace prefix, if such is present or the whole name otherwise) *is one of* `provider_email`, `provider_fax`, `provider_phone` *or* `provider_phone_ext` .

The variable `$recprv` should contain one or more elements (node-set) and every such element is the top of a tree based on the parent --> children relation.

Comment: Great answer, but I am still a bit unclear about the difference between elements, node-set and tree, could you elaborate? Thx.

Comment: @Robert: You need to read a good XPath book, these questions cannot be answered just in a comment or even in as a reply to a separate question. One needs reading and a lot of practice.

Answer (score 2):

$recprv is a variable so the XPATH is acting on the node-set contained in the variable

The local-name() function returns the part of the Element name with-out the namespace URI so for example they would match element names like `<provider_phone />` as well as `<xyz:provider_phone />`