# Question about XPath with functions in it

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

this is a follow-up question of my previous thread:

[Please help me on understanding this XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242922/please-help-me-on-understanding-this-xpath)

I have an XPath as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="position()+count(preceding-sibling::*)-18"/>
```

currently I can only understand the parts of it, like position(). Also, I know that preceding-sibling is to choose all siblings before the current node, but I have no idea what the statement mean when they get combined like above.

Could anyone give some help on understanding this XPath? thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the only correct explanation of what `preceding-sibling::*` really selects. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All answers with the exception of @Alejandro 's have the same common fault**:

**It is not true that**:

```
preceding-sibling::*
```

selects all preceding-sibling nodes.

It only selects all preceding-sibling elements.

**To select all preceding-sibling nodes use**:

```
preceding-sibling::node()
```

**There are these kind of nodes in XPath**:

1. **The root node** (denoted as `/`), also denoted as `document-node()` in XPath 2.0
2. **Element nodes**. such as `<a/>`
3. **Text nodes**. In `<a> Hello </a>`  the text node is the only child of `a` and has a string value of " Hello "
4. **Comment nodes**.  `<!-- This is a comment-->`
5. **Processing instruction nodes**. `<?someName I am a PI ?>`
6. **Attribute nodes**. In `<a x="1"/>` `x` is the only attribute of `a`.
7. **Namespace nodes**. `<a xmlns:my="my:namespace"/>` `a` has a namespace node with value "my:namespace" and name (prefix) `my`

**Nodes of the first 5 kinds can be selected using the `preceding-sibling::` axis**:

```
preceding-sibling::node()
```

selects all sibling nodes of kind 1 to 5.

```
preceding-sibling::*
```

selects all element preceding siblings

```
preceding-sibling::someName
```

selects all elemens named "someName" preceding siblings

```
preceding-sibling::text()
```

selects all text nodes preceding siblings (useful in mixed content)

```
preceding-sibling::comment()
```

selects all comment node preceding siblings.

```
preceding-sibling::processing-instruction()
```

selects all preceding siblings that are PIs

```
preceding-sibling::processing-instruction('someName')
```

selects all preceding siblings that are PIs and are named "someName".

Answer (score 5):

Your expresion is doing some calculation using the static position (from input source) and the dynamic position (from current node list).

Lets see some examples. Suppose this stylesheet and this input:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="list">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(),' + ',
                                         count(preceding-sibling::*),' = ',
                                         position() +
                                         count(preceding-sibling::*))"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

<list>
    <a/>
    <b/>
    <a/>
    <b/>
</list>
```

Output:

```
<list>
    <a>1 + 0 = 1</a>
    <b>2 + 1 = 3</b>
    <a>3 + 2 = 5</a>
    <b>4 + 3 = 7</b>
</list>
```

Now, changing the second rule to `match="a"`:

```
<list>
    <a>1 + 0 = 1</a>
    <a>3 + 2 = 5</a>
</list>
```

So, **patterns don't change the current node list**

What if `position()` is in pattern? Lets change the rule to `match="a[position()=2]"`:

```
<list>
    <a>3 + 2 = 5</a>
</list>
```

Strange? No. In the XPath pattern `position()` works against its own context node list and the axis direction. This case: `child::a[position()=2]` meaning a second `a` child.

This shows that `position()` in patterns works with different context than `position()` in the content template.

So, How change the current context node list? Well, `apply-templates` and `for-each` instructions.

Add now to the `apply-templates` instruction some `select` attribute like `select="a"`:

```
<list>
    <a>2 + 2 = 4</a>
</list>
```

Comment: +1 thanks - I get it now. Was having some problems but resolved them by adding <xsl:apply-templates select="./*"/>

Answer (score 2):

`position()` returns the position of the current node within the node-set being iterated right now. Assume there are four `<foo>` elements:

```
<xml>
  <foo /><foo /><foo /><foo />
</xml>
```

and you iterate them via `<xsl:apply-templates>`:

```
<xsl:template match="/xml">
  <!-- this selects four nodes -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="foo" />
</xsl:template>

<!-- this runs four times -->
<xsl:template match="foo">
  <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
</xsl:template>
```

Then this will output `"1234"`.

`count()` counts the nodes in a node-set.

`preceding-sibling::*` selects all elements on the `preceding-sibling` axis, as seen from the current node *(unless the current node is an attribute, as attributes technically do not have preceding siblings)*.

```
<xsl:value-of select="position()+count(preceding-sibling::*)-18"/>
```

Should be pretty self-explanatory now. The XSLT concept you are probably missing is that of the "current node". The current node is the execution context of your XSLT program. There is always a node that is the current node, and most XSLT/XPath operations implicitly work on the current node.

Comment: Hay guise what's going on in here?

Answer (score 1):

`preceding-sibling::` is an axis which returns a nodeset. In this case, `*` tells it all preceding siblings. `count()` counts the number of nodes in a nodeset. So, this part of the expression gives us the total number of nodes that have the same parent as the current node which appear before it in the document.

Comment: `position()` gives you the position of the current node within the nodeset being evaluated. `+` is addition. As in "1+1".

Comment: What is wrong with this anser: It states that `preceding-sibling::*` selects "all preceding siblings". In fact, it only selects all preceding siblings that are elements. It doesn't select preceding siblings that are other types of nodes -- for example text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

`position()` will evaluate to a number representing the current nodes position within a 1 indexed array of nodes being evaluated. Call that *n*.

`preceding-sibling::*` will evaluate the number of sibling nodes before the current one and count is what it sounds like (and quite likely to be equal to *n*-1 here as it goes).

The -18 should be self-evident :) so what you're left with is a calculation of the position + the number of preceding siblings - 18. That's going to be quite specific to the business concern as to why you want that calculation, but that's what you have.

Comment: Wrong, the number of preceding siblings nodes may generally be different from the number of preceding siblings elements. Not all nodes are elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will result in a number, which will equal:

The position in the **Current** node list, minus the number of any preceding siblings, minus 18.

Generally speaking, different operators can be combined into expressions as you demonstrate in your example.

A note: Use `position()` with caution, because sometimes the current node list is not easy to see.

Comment: +1 For properly relates `position()` to the current node list. It would be excellent with a description of how is set the current node list...