# xslt matching first x items of filtered result set

Tags: xml, xslt, umbraco

Quite new to xslt so forgive me if this is a basic question - I can't find the answer either on SO or by searching on Google.

What I am trying to do is return a filtered set of nodes and then have a template match on the first 1 or 2 items in that set and another template match the remainder. However I don't seem to be able to do this without a `<xsl:for-each />` loop (which is highly undesirable as I may be matching 3000 nodes and only treating 1 differently).

Using `position()` doesn't work as this is unaffected by the filtering. I've tried sorting the result set but this doesn't seem to take effect early enough to affect the template match. The `<xsl:number />` outputs the correct numbers but I can't use these in a match statement.

I've put some example code below. I'm using the unsuitable `position()` method below to illustrate the problem.

Thanks in advance!

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<news>
    <newsItem id="1">
        <title>Title 1</title>
    </newsItem>
    <newsItem id="2">
        <title>Title 2</title>
    </newsItem>
    <newsItem id="3">
        <title></title>
    </newsItem>
    <newsItem id="4">
        <title></title>
    </newsItem>
    <newsItem id="5">
        <title>Title 5</title>
    </newsItem>
</news>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ol>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/news/newsItem [string(title)]" />
        </ol>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="newsItem [position() &lt; 4]">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Desired Result:**

1. Title 1
2. Title 2
3. Title 5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one's actually simpler than you might think. Do:

```
 <xsl:template match="newsItem[string(title)][position() &lt; 4]">
```

And drop the [string(title)] predicate from your `<xsl:apply-templates` select.

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ol>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/news/newsItem" />
        </ol>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="newsItem[string(title)][position() &lt; 4]">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="position()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What you're effectively doing here is applying a second filter (`[position() &lt; 4]`) after your `[string(title)]` filter, which results in the `position()` being applied to the filtered list.

Comment: awesome! I thought that [string(title)][position() &lt; 4] was the equivalent of [string(title) and position() &lt; 4] which didn't work. Did not realise this would make any difference at all. Thought it would be something simple - this will come in handy!

Comment: @Inrbob: For a full explanation of the differences between `position()` function in patterns and in content template, check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344594/question-about-xpath-with-functions-in-it/4347651#4347651) explaning **context node list** issues.