# match first item in a list but also include in full list

Tags: xslt, xslt-grouping

I'm seeking to match the first item in a list but also include the first item in a full list without calling the first item template

given an xml file:

```
<page>
     <set>         
        <item><name>One</name></item>
        <item><name>Two</name></item>
     </set>
</page>
```

and xslt

```
<xsl:template match="page">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="set/item[1]"/>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="set"/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="set">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- match only the first item -->
<xsl:template match="set/item[1]">
FIZZ   
</xsl:template>

<!-- match all the items including the first one -->
<xsl:template match="item">
BUZZ
</xsl:template>
```

My goal is to get FIZZ BUZZ BUZZ. But I get FIZZ FIZZ BUZZ. suggesting that the `set/item[1]` is called from the `<xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>`

im ok with dropping the `set` if needed so the xml would be

```
<item><name>One</name></item>
<item><name>One</name></item>
```

It's similar but different to the following question:
[xslt matching first x items of filtered result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067791/xslt-matching-first-x-items-of-filtered-result-set)

Comment: The purpose of your question is not clear. If your goal is to get  FIZZ FIZZ BUZZ, then you're going about it wrong. Are you asking how to get the desired result, or are you asking for an explanation why your code doesn't produce the result you expect?

Comment: P.S. Your code does **not** produce FIZZ FIZZ BUZZ. XSLT counts from 1, not from 0 and `set/item[0]` does not match anything. If you change it to `set/item[1]` then you will get the result you claim.

Comment: yes it should be item[1]. didnt copy paste and used to the indexing in almost all languages. but otherwise the purpose is exposed in the first line. nevertheless the answer is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial template:

```
<xsl:template match="page">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="set/item[1]"/>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="set"/>
</xsl:template>
```

applies templates to the first item twice: once directly, and once as part of `set`.

Every time you apply templates to a set of nodes, the processor searches for the template that best matches each node in the selected set and applies it. So a template matching `set/item[1]` will be chosen for the first `item` every time it is processed.

---

If you want different processing for the first `item` only once, and then include it with the rest of the set for further processing, you will need to use some other method - e.g. a different [mode](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#modes):

```
<xsl:template match="page">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="set/item[1]" mode="first"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="set"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item" mode="first">
FIZZ   
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
BUZZ
</xsl:template>
```