# xslt: matching position of filtered and sorted result set

Tags: xml, xslt, umbraco

this is a follow up [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067791/xslt-matching-first-x-items-of-filtered-result-set). Basically I need to get the `position()` of items within a filtered *and sorted* collection. Any advice on how to proceed with this?

Thanks!

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<news>
    <newsItem id="1">
        <title>Title 1</title>
    </newsItem>
    <newsItem id="2">
        <title>Title 2</title>
    </newsItem>
    <newsItem id="3">
        <title></title>
    </newsItem>
    <newsItem id="4">
        <title></title>
    </newsItem>
    <newsItem id="5">
        <title>Title 5</title>
    </newsItem>
</news>
```

**XSL:**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <ol>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/news/newsItem [string(title)][3 > position()]">
            <xsl:sort order="descending" data-type="number" select="@id"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ol>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="newsItem">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" />
```

**Desired Result:**

1. Title 5
2. Title 2

**Actual Result:**

1. Title 2
2. Title 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344594/question-about-xpath-with-functions-in-it/4347651#4347651) about context node list.

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ol>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/news/newsItem [string(title)]">
                <xsl:sort order="descending" data-type="number" select="@id"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </ol>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="newsItem">
        <xsl:if test="3 > position()">
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            </li>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<ol>
    <li>Title 5</li>
    <li>Title 2</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: ARRGG!! Thanks for this. I would have preferred a way of making the match on position rather than matching everything then filtering with an if - but this works. I did try reading that answer you posted on my last question, but I must confess I had trouble following it.... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Inrbob: You are welcome! I really recomend you to read that answer... If there is doubts, you can ask them as comments on that.